# Python Nested Dictionary keeps over writing all kay values

Tags: python, dictionary

Basically I am trying to get input from the user and fill a nested dictionary.

Here is a sample run

```
Enter ID: 111
Enter Course number: 2
Enter course, weight, grade: cs100 5 A
Enter course, weight, grade: cs101 6 B
Continue? Y
Enter ID: 222
Enter course number: 1
Enter course, weight, grade: cs102 6 C
Continue? N
```

output:

`{111: {cs100: (5,A), cs101: (6,B)}, 222: {cs102: (6,C)}}`

however the code overwrites the keys and values and I only get the last ID and info entered.

Here is my code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

inp = "Y"
courseDictionary = {}
studentDictionary = {}

while inp != "N":
    studentId = int(input("Enter Student ID: "))

    studentDictionary = defaultdict(dict)

    numberCourses = int(input("Enter number of courses registered: "))

    for i in range(numberCourses):
        courseName, ects, grade = input("Enter course name, ECTS, grade: ").split()
        ects = int(ects)
        studentDictionary[studentId].update({courseName: (ects, grade)})

    inp = input("Do you want to continue Y/N? ")

print(studentDictionary)
```

Comment: please edit your question, with it being formatted correctly

Answer (score 1):

You should move creation of `studentDictionary` outside (before) the loop.

Corrected code below:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVG7asMwFN3vV9x6kiGksUs7BEppkwxZvKRLKB0US04EtmT0IISQb3cl2SQu6VANRtx7Xj5qT/ag5FPXVVo1WKq65qUVShoUTau0RcYr6mrLRGkBhGzxFZNtAqVy2vCliGCqT358voCxjnFp/zMe6ZLwSQGOB1FzDB4P3qRI5oD@DOQ18yQhLfF7Z0mykpZr3PRLXC/nmKReIzCka3ZcL2JC8xerB6CqsBxAmu@F8SvORjqV0ig8GzWVe05@yaZ9uHB6jYI2fIK@PDPBvaaMR@ORaQ9DGXGrxedmwAXDqWlrYUl61Qw6Q/JwvS3uqvy69vM9dS2jlpPzLdEcyShSehn@rH/HId5S4Uk5PFLfo1U@p7RCOo7bx@LNZwNodcgRX@rO3nfVdVmWQQ6lyWYzfMb3eMvwBT9gC3meQxYnuZ8soPgB)

```
from collections import defaultdict

inp = "Y"
courseDictionary = {}
studentDictionary = {}
studentDictionary = defaultdict(dict)

while inp != "N":
    studentId = int(input("Enter Student ID: "))

    numberCourses = int(input("Enter number of courses registered: "))

    for i in range(numberCourses):
        courseName, ects, grade = input("Enter course name, ECTS, grade: ").split()
        ects = int(ects)
        studentDictionary[studentId].update({courseName: (ects, grade)})

    inp = input("Do you want to continue Y/N? ")

print(dict(studentDictionary))
```

Output:

```
{111: {'cs100': (5, 'A'), 'cs101': (6, 'B')}, 222: {'cs102': (6, 'C')}}
```